# What 80s children’s fantasy movie has a scene with a court jester who snaps his fingers and disappears?

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, medieval

I’m looking for a live-action children’s fantasy movie that I remember watching part of in the late 80s.

The only scene I can remember features a kid and a magical court jester outside near a forest. I think the court jester tells him a riddle and then says something about being a fool and then snaps his fingers and disappears.

I think this movie took place in medieval times, or maybe it was modern times and the kid travelled back in time to go on a quest. It might’ve been a miniseries or made-for-TV movie. Anyone know what it might be?

Comment: Could it be Merlin 1998?

Comment: Was this on US TV? UK? Canadian, Australian, other?

Comment: It couldn’t have been Merlin 1998. At the time I watched it it would’ve been no later than 1990.

Comment: This was on US TV.

Comment: Maybe this riddling jester? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwvvAOZVDZQ although he takes a while to get to the riddle. Or, from 1:14 in, his predecessor (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1xKexLAaeQ). For Motley in a forest setting, see https://www.knightmare.com/series/series-6/quest-4.html

Comment: And 14:09 onwards of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppnNhZVeZHI - this includes him teleporting away but he doesn't click his fingers

Comment: If it isn't Knightmare, maybe this episode of T-Bag - although the character who teleported by clicking their fingers wasn't actually the jester. http://hight.50webs.com/series/strikes/ep9.html and video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MGGkOmd03Q - the jester shows up in the woods at 3:40 in this video

Comment: Finger click teleport INTO a scene a bit past 12:42 in - and out of one just past 19:00. Can't find any riddles from the jester though.

Comment: The videos in the first two links aren’t available in my country, but I’m pretty sure it’s not Knightmare. I skimmed through a lot of episodes on YouTube and it doesn’t seem like what I remember. It’s also not that T-Bag episode. I’ll try to look at more episodes of T-Bag, but I feel like what I remember is probably a miniseries. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Knightmare varied a bit by series. It's specifically Series 4 I had in mind, if that helps. There was only AFAIK one other episode of T-Bag with a jester, but that was in a castle, not a forest.

Comment: I actually skimmed through all the Knightmare episodes from the late 80s up to 1990, which is when series 4 was released. I really don’t think it was that show. I have this feeling that it was a miniseries where some kid either traveled back in time or was transported to a fantasy world to go on a quest. I also think it was first released in either ‘89 or ‘90. When I was a kid I always wanted to find out what show/movie it was but never did. It’s funny that I remember being curious about it then and still am to this day! I’m going to do some more research…

Answer (score 14):

With you saying possibly a TV mini series I'm wondering if you saw Timothy Claypole, the mediaeval jester in *[Rentaghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rentaghost)*.
He was a 'sprite ghost' and could indeed disappear.

> The firm, located in South Ealing, is originally run by Fred Mumford, a recently deceased loser who feels he can find work for ghosts whose lives were as unsuccessful as his. His first (and only) recruits are Timothy Claypole, a mischievous jester with a comical lack of knowledge about modern technology, and Hubert Davenport, a delicate Victorian-era gentleman who is morally shocked by the modern world. The ghosts work from an office, which they rent from Harold Meaker, who discovers the truth about them in the third episode.

The series was remade in Australia in the late 1980s

Comment: Didn't he pinch his nose, rather than snapping his fingers?

Comment: @ Clara Diaz Sanchez ..yeah in the original UK series, but I've never seen the Aussie remake

Comment: I’ve been skimming through a bunch of episodes of Rentaghost on YouTube but I haven’t seen the scene I remember. Did this show ever air in the US?

Answer (score 3):

Is it [Krull (1983)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/)?

Titch is a young boy and an apprentice to the Emerald Seer.
Ergo "the Magnificent" is a magician and a goofball, acting very much like a court jester.
In one scene they are traveling through a gloomy swamp (filled with trees).

[image]
Titch (boy in green) standing next to Ergo (man in red pants) while in the swamp.

This conversation takes place:

> Ergo : If I had my wish I'd be out of this gloomy place right away. If I really had my wish I'd be sitting on top of a gooseberry pie as big as a mountain. No, that's a bit greedy. I'll settle for one as big as a house.
> Titch : I'd wish for a puppy.
> Ergo : Only one puppy? If you're wishing why not wish for a hundred?
> Titch : Only want one.
> Ergo : Well that's a **foolish** wish.

Shortly after Ergo sneaks behind a bush and transforms himself into a puppy (disappears), thereby fulfilling Titch’s wish.

Comment: Does he snap his fingers?

Comment: I don't remember him snapping his fingers but it might of happened sometime during the scene. His disappearance was more of a "Where did he run off to?" and less of dramatic disappearance in a puff of smoke. (My guess is he did not snap his fingers, but everything else seems to match.)

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s not Krull. The scene I remember had a jester acting silly and he snapped his fingers and disappeared. He might’ve only appeared in one scene. I think this movie/show was meant for young kids and probably made for TV. I have a very vague memory of a kid being transported to a forest area and then he came across the jester, and I believe the jester tried to give him a clue about something in the form of a riddle. I don’t know if the kid travelled back in time, but I just feel like I remember he came from somewhere else and magically appeared in the forest area.

Comment: I believe the movie/series is similar to The Chronicles of Narnia. I skimmed through the BBC Chronicles of Narnia series from 1988 but I didn’t see a scene like the one I remembered.